# React: how to access base class from higher order components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

So I have a `BaseComponent.jsx` that I extend on many of my components. This works great.

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.something = true
    }
}

class OtherComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.log(this.something) // true
    }
}
```

But now I need to use `withRouter(component)` from `react-router` which wraps your component in a higher order component and decorates your class.

So I do this:

```
class OtherComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.log(this.something) // undefined
    }
}

export default withRouter(OtherComponent)
```

The problem is that now I can't access the properties from `BaseComponent` and those return `undefined`.

How can I solve this so that I can create a HoC and at the same time access the properties of the base class?

Comment: I don't see the same behavior. I created a fiddle based on your example and it correctly logs `true`.  Add that it should be working as you described and as this fiddle illustrates since HoC's don't alter the component they are composing. https://jsfiddle.net/okpLvu3e/

Comment: Hey @RyanDuffy this simple example works but when you start adding children, etc it doesn't. Check this: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3514 They simply don't recommend extending React.Component.

Comment: Can you achieve what you want with component composition instead? Subclassing is discouraged when developing React components.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly based on the linked issue, you want to extend a component that has been wrapped with `withRouter` which isn't possible. You could export both a wrapped and unwrapped version and use the latter for extension. That all said, as @loganfsmyth suggested, composition is likely a better solution but it's difficult to say given your example.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to forget about inheritance if I want to use `withRouter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Extending React components is discouraged by the React team. Even if it works on some instances, the results are unpredictable when doing fancier things such as higher order components.

> General extending component classes should be avoided, and even if used, should not be used on "smart" connected components anyway – prefer composition over inheritance for React components.

And

> You cannot implement a generic HoC that extends a component for the simple reason that the HoC has to work with all three forms of React component declaration.

Source: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3514

So the answer to my question is simply that it can't be done and I should move to composition instead of inheritance.